# Multiple slick sliders on the same page duplicates the first element

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

Using multiple `slick` sliders on the same page results in duplicated content even if the original content is not duplicated.

The effect of using slick on multiple elements in the same page results in replacing the content of all elements with the content from first element.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="product-slick-general" id="product-slick-1>
    .... // content goes here and respects the slick html structure
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.product-slick-general').each(function() {    
    $(this).slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        autoplay: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 991,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    dots: false,
                    arrows: true,
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                }
            },
        ]
    });

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with your selector not being specific enough. You could use the id instead.

```
let $productSliders = $(document).find('.product-slick-general');
for (let i = 0; i < $productSliders.length; i++) {
  let index = i + 1;
  $('#product-slick-' + index).slick(
  {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 2,
    autoplay: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    dots: true,
    arrows: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 991,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
        }
    },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                arrows: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        },
    ]
})
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result